# How to change data type to Date/Time using direct query mode

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

When i want to use a Date column in this mode it shows as a Varchar/string type. So, when i try to change it from Direct Query it accepts the Date Format, but the DataType still remains as a Varchar/STR. I need to create some Time Intelligence formulas (Basically a DateDiff).

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: if you change the datatype its will be change on data model surly. are you sure for chose apply and close bottom?? if you sure please send more detail about your problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. What I needed to do it's to add a column and there i was able to create the DATEDIFF to check if a task was done on schedule or it expired like this ->

IF(DATEDIFF(TODAY(),tblTask[DueDate],DAY) < TODAY(), "Expired")

I Don't understand why I couldn't write as a DAX measure without needing to add a column.

Thanks anyway.